# 404 error with a 2nd Wordpress install in a sub-directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

Lots of topics similar to this one but nothing seems to have worked so far. First time posting on this site - apologies if I miss off anything vital!!

Current site is - http://www.mansfordwebdesign.com - working fine but I want a 2nd Wordpress install as a development environment. I've created a subfolder called 'ilead' via my FTP and uploaded the Wordpress files.

When I go to http://www.mansfordwebdesign.com/ilead/wp-activate.php or any other related Wordpress file I get a 404 error.

Both sites have a .htaccess file - the first is -

```
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`
```

The second is

```
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ilead/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`
```

Is something wrong in these files or could it be anything to do with my WHM or CPanel controls??

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the RewriteBase line to what is below for the subfolder..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ilead/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ilead/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```